Setting up a bootable USB with gparted in Eolementary OS running on a Mac
I created a bootable usb for Elementary on my 2011 mac mini in High Sierra using disc utility then Etcher.
I am now wanting to set up a dual boot for the two HDD's on my Mac so I can have High Sierra again for things like iTunes.
What options do I need to select in gparted so that it'll be bootable on my mac and ready for Etcher? Does this matter now that the computer runs solely on a linux os?
Very new to all this so feel free to dumb things down as much as possible and chuck in any other useful advice.
Cheers
Alex
